# string interpolation to external link without http://

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using string interpolation to allow a user to put in a website on their profile and then link to it externally as follows.

```
<%= link_to truncate(@user.portfolio_title, :length => 17), 
"http://#{@user.portfolio}", :target => "_blank"  %>
```

But when a user puts in a link with "Http://" it ends up spitting out "http://http://apple.com".

But if I delete the http:// from the interpolation it won't turn into an external link. It basically appends the full link to my existing host URL.

How would I fix this?

Comment: IMHO the best way to solve this is to automatically add `http://` when the user doesn't give it and then store that in the DB. What if the user adds `https://example.com`? (note the `https`, and not `http` here)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker ok i'm open to that. how would i do that?

Comment: You should also post the code that removes the `http://` part, perhaps you made an error in the code?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker i actually don't have that code. right now it just takes the link as it.

Comment: `"http://http://apple.com".split("//").uniq.join("//")` If there is `http` in @user.portfolio it sets only one http and if there is not http://  then add only one http:// prefix.

Comment: @Shadow awesome. so would it be `{@user.portfolio}.split("//").uniq.join("//")` ?

Comment: @rs19 Yes Correct but if `@user.portfolio` do not contain http://  then u have to think buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to sanitize user input once (when the user inputs that data) and not every time the data is rendered. To do so, add the following to your model:

```
# in app/models/user.rb
def portfolio=(url)
  if url.present?
    url = url.match(/https?:\/\//) ? url : "http://#{url}"
    write_attribute(:portfolio, url)
  end
end
```

Then use it in your view like this:

```
<%= link_to truncate(@user.portfolio_title, length: 17), 
            @user.portfolio, rel: 'noopener', target: '_blank' %>
```

Note: For [security reasons](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) you may want to use `target: '_blank'` always together with `rel: 'noopener'`.

Comment: awesome thanks. do i need to re migrate after implementing this or anything?

Comment: Sanitize existing records by running: `User.find_each { |u| u.update(portfolio: u.portfolio) }` in your Rails console.

Comment: ok awesome. so everything works except it doesn't open in the link in a new window.

Comment: @rs19: Sorry, you should use both (`target` and `rel`). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put this sample code in a helper and get what you need

```
    def link_helper link

        if link[0..3] == "http" or link[0..4] == "https"
            link
        else
            "//#{link}"
        end
    end
```

Comment: Is it same to assume that the portfolio page always supports the same protocol then the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

Strip `http://` from begining:

```
<%= link_to truncate(@user.portfolio_title, :length => 17), 
"http://#{@user.portfolio.sub(%r!^http://!i, '')}", :target => "_blank"  %>
```